# LinkageError during weblogic startup

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

When I deploy my `ear` project into weblogic, during application startup the `LinkageError` appears as follow:

```
<Jun 11, 2018 5:31:00 PM IRDT> <Error> <WLSS.Setup> <BEA-331210> <Skip SIP related logic, because error occurs when parsing sip related annotations of "DSwar"
com.bea.wcp.sip.engine.server.setup.SipAnnotationParsingException: 
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.engine.server.setup.SipAnnotationData.<init>(SipAnnotationData.java:155)
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.util.DeploymentUtil.getOrCreateAnnotationData(DeploymentUtil.java:70)
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.util.DeploymentUtil.isSipModule(DeploymentUtil.java:96)
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.engine.server.SipServerTailModule$1.visit(SipServerTailModule.java:127)
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.engine.server.SipServerTailModule.visitAllContexts(SipServerTailModule.java:112)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Jun 11, 2018 5:31:06 PM IRDT> <Error> <WLSS.Setup> <BEA-331210> <Skip SIP related logic, because error occurs when parsing sip related annotations of "TTMS"
com.bea.wcp.sip.engine.server.setup.SipAnnotationParsingException: 
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.engine.server.setup.SipAnnotationData.<init>(SipAnnotationData.java:155)
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.util.DeploymentUtil.getOrCreateAnnotationData(DeploymentUtil.java:70)
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.util.DeploymentUtil.isSipModule(DeploymentUtil.java:96)
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.engine.server.SipServerTailModule$1.visit(SipServerTailModule.java:127)
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.engine.server.SipServerTailModule.visitAllContexts(SipServerTailModule.java:112)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.setResourceLoader(Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;)V" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/GenericClassLoader) of the current class, org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/FreeMarkerConfigurer, and the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) for interface org/springframework/context/ResourceLoaderAware have different Class objects for the type org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader used in the signature
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2547)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1410)
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.engine.server.setup.SipAnnotationData.classAnnotationParsing(SipAnnotationData.java:344)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

The version of weblogic is `10.3.6.0`

Answer (score 1):

This conflict could be because one of your application is having a class (org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader) in one of jar's which is conflicting with one of weblogic's embedded jar(http://www.findjar.com/class/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html)  and class of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the *JVM* has run out of space in the *permanent generation*(`Perm Gen`).

Increase the *Perm Gen* space in the java options of the *Admin Server* in *setDomainEnv.sh*.

It can be resized according to the requirement using

***-XX:MaxPermSize*** and ***-XX:PermSize***

*JVM* Options.

The following needs to be set :

```
USER_MEM_ARGS=-Xms2048m -Xms2048m -XX:PermSize=512 -XX:MaxPermSize=1024
```

And then, try to restart *Admin Server*.

If there exists no problem with those parameters, then

***node.properties*** file may be edited to change these parameters:

```
- SecureListener = false(by default is true)
- StartScriptEnabled = true 
- StopScriptEnabled = true
```

Comment: this is my vm arguments `java -client   -Xms4G -Xmx5G -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=1G  -XX:MaxPermSize=4G`